# How to use BeautifulSoup to match text in <div></div> where there is embedded <a></a>?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have the following BeautifulSoup code in `test.py`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# vim: set noexpandtab tabstop=2 shiftwidth=2 softtabstop=-1:

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import sys
soup = BeautifulSoup(sys.stdin.read(), 'html.parser', from_encoding='utf-8')

import re
from pprint import pprint
pprint(soup.find('div', text=re.compile(r'Scientific')))
```

Here are two html files:

test1.html

```
<div class="heading4">Scientific/Research Contact(s)</div>
```

test2.html

```
<div class="heading4"><a name="_Scientific/Research_Contact(s)"></a>Scientific/Research Contact(s)</div>
```

Here are the search results.

```
$ ./test.py < test1.html
<div class="heading4">Scientific/Research Contact(s)</div>
$ ./test.py < test2.html
None
```

Does anybody know why the second one can not be found?

Comment: If you have lxml, `root.xpath('//div[contains(text(), "Scientific")]')` works equally well for both cases.

Answer (score 1):

When searching elements by name and text, `BeautifulSoup` checks the [`.string`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#string) of an element to match a desired text. This confusing behavior is  actually covered in the [documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#id18):

> If you pass one of the find* methods both string and a tag-specific argument like name, *Beautiful Soup will search for tags that match your tag-specific criteria and whose `Tag.string` matches your value for string*. It will not find the strings themselves. Previously, Beautiful Soup ignored the tag-specific arguments and looked for strings.

In the second case, the `.string` of the `div` element is `None` - this is why you are not getting any results. Instead, find the text node directly:

```
soup.find(text=re.compile(r"Scientific"))
```

And, if you would need the actual parent element, you can get it from the `.parent`:

```
soup.find(text=re.compile(r"Scientific")).parent
```